# How to Tar files and exclude directories and "." files

Tags: tar

I am installing Ubuntu on new computer and am transfering files from my old computer(Ubuntu). In my home directory I want to tar all files but exclude directories and '.'files. I can't find a tar exclude to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: Don't understand what you are asking. How can you exclude directories but extract files?

Comment: "I can't find a tar exclude to do this." sorry? tar does have an option for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please provide an example with `tar -t` output and which entries you want to include/exclude?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want, but you can exclude N number of folders from the file names using `--strip-components` option.

For example, this will extract the files skipping the top-level folder

```
tar -xf har-tools.tar --strip-components 1
```

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295908/1039893) suggests another approach, but you have to delete the folders with another command.

```
tar xf har-tools.tar --transform='s/.*\///'
```

This basically replaces the all leading path entries to empty strings with only the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Well I recommend you to do the logic as follows :

First find the required files in your home directory and then tar it to archive.

```
find /path/to/home -type f -print0 | tar -cvzf backup.tar.gz --null -T -
```

This will help to find files , normal find command ignores all hidden files. Probably while backing up files there arise a common issue of spacing in file names to ignore that *--null* is used and in tar function -cvzf explains as create,verbose,compress,filename.
I hope this works well for you. Cheers.